# Why is Jest running the typescript test files and then the compiled JS test files?

Tags: express, jestjs

When I run Jest, I get 9 failing, 11 passing out of a total of 20, but there are only 10 tests between two different test files, here it is:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const assert = require('assert');
import * as jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
import * as auth from '../services/authentication-service';

const JWT_ERROR_INVALID_SIG = 'invalid signature';


describe('MMD Integration', () => {
  const SERVICE = "knox";
  const SERVICE_ID = "aluna1";
  const badPublicKeyFile = "badkey.pub";

  describe('Service Config is accessible', () => {
    it('should contain data', async (done) => {
      let config: {} | null = null;
      config = await auth.getServiceConfig().catch(err => {
        console.log("caught getServiceConfig error:", err);
        return null;
      });
      if (config != null) {
        assert.include(Object.keys(config), SERVICE);
      } else {
        console.log("Test failed!");
      }
    });
  });

  describe('Public Key', () => {
    describe('is valid', () => {
      it('should decode successfully', async (done) => {
        let config: {} | null = null;
        config = await auth.getServiceConfig().catch(err => {
          console.log("caught getServiceConfig error:", err);
          return null;
        });
        let publicKey: string | null = null;
        if (config) {
          publicKey = await auth.getServicePublicKey(SERVICE, config).catch(err => {
            console.log("caught getServicePublicKey error:", err);
            return null;
          });
          const token = await auth.genJwt(SERVICE);
          if (token == null) {
            console.log("genJwt returned null: stopping test");
            done();
          } else if (!publicKey) {
            console.log("No public key: stopping test");
            done();
          } else {
            jwt.verify(token, publicKey, (err, decoded) => {
              if (err) {
                console.log("WARNING: valid public key failed!", err.message);
              } else if (decoded && Object.keys(decoded).includes('vendor')) {
                assert.include(Object.values(decoded), SERVICE);
              } else {
                console.log("Test failed!");
              }
            });
          }
        }
      });
    });

    describe('is bad', () => {
      const badPublicKey = fs.readFileSync(badPublicKeyFile);
      it('should fail verify', async (done) => {
        const token = await auth.genJwt(SERVICE);
        if (token == null) {
          console.log("genJwt returned null: stopping test");
          done();
        } else {
          jwt.verify(token, badPublicKey, (err: any, decoded: any) => {
            if (err) {
              assert.equal(err.message, JWT_ERROR_INVALID_SIG);
            } else {
              console.log("WARNING: bad public key worked!", decoded);
            }
          });
        }
      });
    });
  });

  describe('Verify Service', () => {
    describe('with valid public key', () => {
      it('should succeed', async (done) => {
        try {
          const token = await auth.genJwt(SERVICE);
          if (token == null) {
            console.log("genJwt returned null: stopping test");
            done();
          } else {
            const result = await auth.verifyService(SERVICE, token).catch(err => {
              console.log("caught verifyService error: stopping test", err);
              throw new Error(err);
            });
            assert.equal(result, "OK");
          }
        } catch (err) {
          assert.equal(err, "OK");
        }
      });
    });

    describe('with mismatch token', () => {
      it('should fail', async (done) => {
        try {
          const result = await auth.verifyService(SERVICE, "xyz").catch(err => {
            console.log("caught verifyService error: stopping test", err);
            done();
          });
        } catch (err) {
          assert.notEqual(err, "OK");
        }
      });
    });
  });

  describe('Service as real MMD', () => {
    it('should fail', async (done) => {
      try {
        const token = await auth.genJwt("mmd");
        if (token == null) {
          console.log("genJwt returned null: stopping test");
          throw new Error('null token');
        } else {
          const result = await auth.verifyService("mmd", token).catch(err => {
            console.log("caught verifyService error:", err);
            throw new Error(err);
          });
        }
      } catch (err) {
        assert.notEqual(err, "OK");
        console.log(err);
      }
    });
  });

});

describe('Get Token from Request Header', () => {
  const someToken = "fake-jwt";
  const headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    , 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + someToken
    , 'Aluna-Service': 'foobar'
  };
  const badHeaders2 = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    , 'Authorization': someToken
    , 'Aluna-Service': 'foobar'
  };

  describe('Request header has authorization', () => {
    it('should return token', () => {
      const result = auth.getTokenFromAuth(headers.Authorization);
      assert.equal(result, someToken);
    });
  });

  describe('Request header is missing authorization', () => {
    it('should return null', () => {
      const result = auth.getTokenFromAuth('');
      assert.equal(result, null);
    });
  });

  describe('Authorization is missing Bearer', () => {
    it('should return null', () => {
      const result = auth.getTokenFromAuth(badHeaders2.Authorization);
      assert.equal(result, null);
    });
  });
});


import request from 'supertest';
import { app } from '../app';

it('renders a greeting to screen', () => {
  return request(app).get('/').send({ greeting: 'howdy' }).expect(200);
})
```

This is what I see in the terminal:

```
Test Suites: 3 failed, 1 passed, 4 totaload:flatten Completed in 1ms
Tests:       9 failed, 11 passed, 20 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        31.358 s
Ran all test suites.

Watch Usage
 › Press f to run only failed tests.
 › Press o to only run tests related to changed files.
 › Press p to filter by a filename regex pattern.
 › Press t to filter by a test name regex pattern.
 › Press q to quit watch mode.
 › Press Enter to trigger a test run.

ReferenceError: You are trying to `import` a file after the Jest environment has been torn down.

      at Object.getCodec (node_modules/iconv-lite/lib/index.js:65:27)
      at Object.getDecoder (node_modules/iconv-lite/lib/index.js:127:23)
      at getDecoder (node_modules/raw-body/index.js:45:18)
      at readStream (node_modules/raw-body/index.js:180:15)
      at getRawBody (node_modules/raw-body/index.js:108:12)
[2022-03-07T18:40:25.852Z] 1.0.1-dev error: uncaughtException: This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). The promise rejected with the reason "Error: Caught error after test environment was torn down
```

This API was meant to work with Jest or that was the original testing suite installed, but someone else came behind and started using Mocha that they are using globally on their machine. Would anyone mind also sharing why tests would pass on their global install of Mocha but not on Jest?

Comment: can you show the test outcome that jest is showing in console?

Comment: @sid, yep I just did.

Comment: Try using `--verbose` to see what tests are actually running. Also, not sure if might be part of the problem, but your tests should be very deterministic. The fact that you are conditionally checking the results of the items you're testing is... missing the point of tests and likely an indication of problematic code.

Comment: @RyanWheale, love what you wrote about having deterministic tests, since I did not write those tests, could you provide some documentation I can give this individual?

Comment: @RyanWheale, also do you mind pointing out a test here that is the best example of conditionally checking the results of the items being tested? Or would you say its just all of them?

Comment: @RyanWheale, its showing 20 tests because its going into the `build/test` files and running those. Not sure why that is happening.

Comment: Jest will automatically look for all test files in your project. You need to tell it to ignore the `build` directory. Regarding good tests - you should be able to call a function and get an expected result. If your function depends on an external service/database/etc, your tests should mock those services or seed the database so that you can run the tests deterministically (eg. returns the same results every time). Tests should never really talk to an external API - rather you mock the API so that your tests can run. If the API has different responses, you should mock all of those.

Comment: @RyanWheale, ahh that's what you meant, thats actually what I do when I am in charge of developing tests and I had forgotten these are referred to as deterministic. Yeah these tests were not written by me and now I have the fun privilege of rewriting them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just wanted to post a solution which is not buried in comments.

By default jest will find any test files in your entire project. If you are building or copying files to a build/release directory, you need to do one of the following:

- (Recommended) Exclude the test files from your build pipeline. I usually create a separate tsconfig for building which excludes the test files. Your build command should point to this tsconfig: `tsc --project tsconfig.build.json`. Note: you can extend tsconfigs so that you don't have to manage duplicates. Here's an example of what your tsconfig.build.json might look like:

  ```json
  {
    "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
    "exclude": ["src/**/*.test.ts"]
  }
  ```

-- OR --

- Exclude your build directories from jest, adding `testPathIgnorePatterns: ['dist/']` to your `jest.config.js` (assuming your compiled JavaScript files are in the `dist` folder)